# Protobuf-net: How to exclude read-only properties(with only getters) from porto contract of implicit all public fields?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, protobuf-net

I am using protobuf-net serialization in my project with stating [ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)] approach.

My class has some properties with only getters in them. i.e read-only properties.
Serializer tries to serialize those properties but throws an error saying unable to change this property.

Currently I have added [ProtoIgnore] attribute on such properties, which is working.

What I wanted to know was whether there is an alternative method to make it ignore all properties that don't have setters. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope; all is all. Actually, I very rarely recommend using implicit fields (see the warnings in the intellisense).

Comment: That's not smart at all! 
There should be a read-only exception. It should also be possible to set exceptions, at least through the [Ignore] attribute.

Comment: @Mentor most people expect readonly types to still work in serializers; protobuf-net can assign to readonly fields - "readonly" is more guidance than a rule